# Runtime 424, Object Required on a Excel Macro, VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i'm getting the runtime 424 error when running this line of code:

```
dateOriginal = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, dw, dateOriginal)
```

Does anyone has any idea of why is this error appearing?

Comment: While writing out a full `DateAdd` function may help make sense of your code, it isn't really necessary in this case. A day is equal to 1 so `dateOriginal = dateOriginal + dw` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

Substitute number for 1 as number of days

```
DateAdd("d",1, dateOriginal)
```